# Disable flow-rule when using upsert for customer-repository

Tags: php, symfony, shopware6

I am importing customers through a plugin by calling

```
$this->customerRepository->upsert([$newUser], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

When running this line of code, Shopware 6 tries to send a email to the customer.

I guess this happens because of a flow-rule.

What is the best way to disable sending an email in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `skipTriggerFlow` state to the context, that way the flows should not be triggered.

```php
$context = Context::createDefaultContext();
$context->addState(Context::SKIP_TRIGGER_FLOW);

$this->customerRepository->upsert([$newUser], $context);
```

This should deactivate the flow execution for all operations you do with that context.